# Compact normed real - spaces.

Tags: compactness, normed-spaces

Is there a compact normed real space which contains more than one element?

Im trying to grab some intuition on this subject. Would love to get some intuition if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. Such a space would have a vector $v\ne0$, and then the sequence $(nv)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ would have no convergent subsequence (since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|nv\|=\infty$). So, the space is not compact.

Comment: So the only normed space which satiesfies this is the zero space?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.